# Docker + Angular: docker arguments doesn't work with ng build

Tags: angular, docker, aws-codebuild

I have an argument called `STAGE` when building the docker image I provide this argument to `docker build` like so:

```
docker build --build-arg STAGE=test -t my-image:latest .
```

the STAGE value is the environment I want to use in my angular app but the build is not working as expected.
**The Dockerfile:**

```
FROM node:10.21.0
ARG STAGE
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli@9.1.8

# install dependencies
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json /app
COPY yarn.lock /app
RUN yarn add enhanced-resolve@^3.1.0
RUN yarn install --pure-lockfile

# build the frontend
COPY . /app
RUN ng build --configuration=$STAGE && cp favicon.png dist/

ENV ENVIRONMENT=$STAGE

# start the server
CMD node server.js
```

as you can see in the Dockerfile I build the Angular app using a specific environment, and I run a node server to serve the app, and at the same time I add an environment variable to the node container that contains the value of the `STAGE` argument in this line `ENV ENVIRONMENT=$STAGE`

The weird part is that the STAGE value sometimes contains a value and sometimes it's empty, how did I know that ?
I'm writing a `console.log(environment)` in both, Angular app and node server file
In Angular I get the default environment although the environment should be **"test"** and in node I get the correct value of the `STAGE` argument which is **"test"**.
**As a summary:**
This line `RUN ng build --configuration=$STAGE && cp favicon.png dist/` the **STAGE** value is empty
and in this line `ENV ENVIRONMENT=$STAGE` it contains a value!!
and also this happens only on **AWS's CodeBuild** when building the project, when I run the docker build locally it works fine!
Any thoughts on why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot replicate your issue, but you may try to substitute

```
ENV ENVIRONMENT=$STAGE

# start the server
CMD node server.js
```

with

```
CMD /bin/sh ENVIRONMENT=$STAGE node server.js
```

Please tell me if it works.

**Edit**

The instruction `RUN ng build --configuration=$STAGE` should get the value for `$STAGE` from environment, and not from docker build argument, so you rewrite you docker file as follow:

```
FROM node:10.21.0

ARG STAGE
ENV ENVIRONMENT=$STAGE

RUN npm install -g @angular/cli@9.1.8

# install dependencies
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json /app
COPY yarn.lock /app
RUN yarn add enhanced-resolve@^3.1.0
RUN yarn install --pure-lockfile

# build the frontend
COPY . /app
RUN ng build --configuration=$ENVIRONMENT && cp favicon.png dist/

# start the server
CMD node server.js
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but the problem is not with node, it's with Angular when running `ng build --configuration=STAGE` the STAGE value is empty!

Comment: I understand, I am going to edit my post...

Comment: still not working and Angular does need an environment variable, we just need to provide a value to the --configuration flag example: `--configuration=test` but I want it to be dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to move the `ENV ENVIRONMENT=$STAGE` right after you define your arg `ARG STAGE`

and point to $ENVIRONMENT in your ng build - `ng build --configuration=$ENVIRONMENT`

also make sure to supply the argument when building the image

`docker build --build-arg STAGE=test .`

Comment: thanks for your reply, I did but it's not working!

Comment: how are you running the build in AWS CodeBuild and where does the argument get supplied from? Seems to me the argument is not supplied when you run the build in CodeBuild

Comment: no, it is supplied and the proof is that when running the container and seeing the logs I found that the value of ENVIRONMENT is test which means it wasn't empty, I provide the value via the environment variable of codebuild

Comment: And CodeBuild is running your refactored Dockerfile?

Comment: yes, just question: is there a rule that say the ENV variable should be declared right after the ARG variables?

Comment: it doesn't have to be declared right after ARG, but you HAVE to declare it before you run `ng build --configuration=$STAGE`